# What is wrong with the syntax in this python code?

Tags: python

**i made some arrangements in the positions of some rows and now the code looks like this**

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def elbow_plot(data, maxK=40, seed_centroids=None):

    sse = {}
for k in range(1, maxK):
  print("k:", k)
  if seed_centroids is not None:
    seeds = seed_centroids.head(k)
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = k, max_inter= 500, n_init=100, random_state=0, init=np.reshape(seeds, (k,1))).fit(data)
    data["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_

  else:
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=300, n_init=100, random_state=0).fit(data)
    data["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_

  sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_
  plt.figure()
  plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()))
  plt.show()
return
elbow_plot(X, maxK=10)
```

**so i made some changes. and now this error pops up**

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-100-69e2bdc4db8e> in <module>()
      9     """
     10     sse = {}
---> 11 for k in range(1, maxK):
     12   print("k:", k)
     13   if seed_centroids is not None:

NameError: name 'maxK' is not defined
```

Comment: Please format it properly so we can see however the error tells you that line 23 isn't indented properly. Please check your tabs/spaces on that line.

Comment: Don't include code as images - keep code inline in your post, properly indented. You can use the `{}` button to make the editor properly wrap it as code.

Comment: Your identation is broken, `for k in range(1, maxK):` needs to go one more tab in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D

def elbow_plot(data, maxK=40, seed_centroids=None):
    sse = {}
    for k in range(1, maxK):
        print("k: ", k)
        if seed_centroids is not None:
            seeds = seed_centroids.head(k)
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=500, n_init=100, random_state=0, init=np.reshape(seeds, 
(k,1))).fit(data)
            data["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_
        else:
            kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=k, max_iter=300, n_init=100, random_state=0).fit(data)
            data["clusters"] = kmeans.labels_
        # Inertia: Sum of distances of samples to their closest cluster center
        sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(list(sse.keys()), list(sse.values()))
    plt.show()
    return

elbow_plot(X, maxK=10)
```

Try running this.
Their seems to be a problem with indentation in plt.figure().

Make sure that the for loop is within the function because your function is returning something. So leave a tab space before this code sippet `for k in range(1, maxK):`

Comment: Surely `return` should be outside of the loop?

Comment: `return` should lie within the funcition because it's got to return back to elbow_plot() caller

Comment: yes, in the function, but outside of the loop. The way you have it now, that for loop can only ever run for a single iteration, making it pointless. i.e. you have indented `return` with 8 spaces instead of 4

Comment: oh I get it, sure thanks

Comment: tbh I imagine everything from `plt.figure()` down to `return` needs to be taken out of the loop

Comment: I think including `sse[k] = kmeans.inertia_` as well right

Comment: I doubt that because `k` is the iterating variable